# How do you solve a two variable 2nd degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Somebody else already asked something similar although I believe this method does not apply to my case. [Solving system of multivariable 2nd-degree polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520945/solving-system-of-multivariable-2nd-degree-polynomials)

My problem is the following. I have:

x^2 + y^2 + 2xy - y

I need to solve for y. I am not good at math so this might be a silly question. I know how to solve single variable second degree polynomials, but cannot find the way to get the solution in the answer key:

y = -x - x^2  and y = -x + x^2

How can I do this? Is there a name for this formula or method? Thank you

Comment: Apply quadratic formula to $(1)y^2 + (2x-1)y + x^2=0$, where I've grouped it to more clearly be a quadratic polynomial in $y$ (whose coefficients just happen to include some $x$s).

Comment: Thank you. Its clear now what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the quadratic formula to the equation with respect to $y$: 
$$
y^2 + (2x - 1) y + x^2 = 0.
$$
This yields 
$$
y = \frac{1 - 2x \pm \sqrt{ 1 - 4x } }{2}.
$$
As this does not yield the answers you expect, perhaps you entered a wrong term in the problem expression?